# Android character sizes

Tags: android, textview, size, space, ansi

I have a client socket which sends some lines (ANSI encoding) which forms a shape. The problem is that in the log cat, when i print out the lines, they form a complete shape, but in my Layout, textviews are not forming the shape even when they have the same length. I can see that the problem lies with the byte size of the space character. But since i can see it on the log cat, there must be a way to set the textviews to form a complete shape. I tried to replace all the space characters with   and set the texts as an html form but still no luck. Is there a way that I'm missing?

```
    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        private BufferedReader input;


        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                InetAddress servAddress = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socked = new Socket(servAddress, SERVERPORT);
                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socked.getInputStream(), "windows-1252"));
                while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    String read = input.readLine();
                    updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
    class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
        String msg;
        public updateUIThread (String str) {
            this.msg = str;

        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView tv = new TextView(cont);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
//          tv.setText(makeTextWithColors(msg));
//          tv.setText(msg + "count: " + msg.length());
            tv.setText(msg);
            screen.addView(tv);
            scroller.post(new Runnable() { 
                public void run() { 
                    scroller.smoothScrollTo(0, screen.getBottom());
                } 
            }); 
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about ASCII art?

Comment: Use a monospaced font. Make sure you're using UTF-8 encoding. OR use an "iconic font" (which is a special font that features special symbols)

Answer (score 3):

It seems

```
tv.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
```

did the trick. It is a font that makes all characters with the same width.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tb;   

tb.setTextSize(20);
```

**tb** = Text View it will get floating point value of size you can put there integral type value

Comment: @Barriscan i think it will help u